# How to loop through an object of arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

For the below code,

```
const groupbysubject = {
                    "Mathematics":
                    [
                      {totalStudents: "23", average: "78", class: "2"},
                      {totalStudents: "25", average: "80", class: "3"}
                    ],
                    "English":
                    [
                      {totalStudents: "33", average: "98", class: "2"},
                      {totalStudents: "35", average: "99", class: "3"}
                    ],
                    "Science":
                    [
                      {totalStudents: "43", average: "65", class: "2"},
                    ]
                  }

                

var isEnglishPresent = Object.fromEntries(
                           Object.entries(groupbysubject).filter(
                             ([key, val])=> key.includes("English")
                            )
                        );
```

I want the following output :

> "33"
> "98"
> "2"
> "35"
> "99"
> "3"

I have filtered the above groupbysubject object into isEnglishPresent object.
How do I proceed further to iterate over isEnglishPresent and get the above output.
Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have an English array with N objects like below.

```
const English = [
  {totalStudents: "33", average: "98", class: "2"},
  {totalStudents: "35", average: "99", class: "3"},
  ...
]
```

Here's how you extract all the values and put it into an array.

```
English.map(item => Object.values(item)).flat()
```

Here's the output

```
["33", "98", "2", "35", "99", "3"]
```

Comment: Instead of `.map()` followed by `.flat()` there's the [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 4):

You want a *flat* list of the *values* from the items inside the `English` key:

```js
const groupbysubject = {
  "Mathematics":
  [
    {totalStudents: "23", average: "78", class: "2"},
    {totalStudents: "25", average: "80", class: "3"}
  ],
  "English":
  [
    {totalStudents: "33", average: "98", class: "2"},
    {totalStudents: "35", average: "99", class: "3"}
  ],
  "Science":
  [
    {totalStudents: "43", average: "65", class: "2"},
  ]
};

var englishData = groupbysubject.English.flatMap(item => Object.values(item));

console.log(englishData);
```

Comment: Thank you but what if the in the output we only need totalStudents of English. How will we do that then?

Comment: @ApoorvaOjha Why did your question not say from the start what you need?

Comment: Also, read my code, understand what it does, experiment a little, and you will figure it out. You don't depend on me making it copy-and-paste ready for you.

Comment: Although my answer is being accepted, I appreciate this less code `flatMap` approach

Comment: @Andus It's a moot point anyway, as it only solves the problem the OP asked for, not the problem the OP wanted to solve.